# Leer y extraer datos de un archivo .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

***¿Cómo puedo extraer información de un documento '.txt'?***

**Necesito:**

Una función que extraiga la información y la introduzca en la posición x en una frase introducida por terminal.

**Es decir:**

Introduzco por terminal:
`Un niño llamado 0 jugaba al futbol con 1 y 2`
**sustituir los números** por **palabras guardadas en un archivo .txt**

Ejemplo:

**Texto introducido por terminal**

`Un niño llamado 0 jugaba al futbol con 1 y 2`

**Archivo .txt**

```
Paco:Luis:Manuel
Jose:Jhony:Roberto
```

**Resultado**

```
Un niño llamado Paco jugaba al futbol con Luis y Manuel
```

Se leer el archivo y guardar la información de este, pero a la hora de intentar cambiar el texto que introduzco no entiendo como puedo hacerlo, llevo esto:

```
def cambiar_texto_en_posicion(arg,ruta_archivo):

    archivo = open(ruta_archivo, "r")
    datos = archivo.read().split(":")
    print(datos)
    archivo.close()

    new_args = arg
    print(new_args)

cambiar_texto_en_posicion("1 juega con 2 y 0","..\entornoServidor\classes\exercises/filename.txt")
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Buenas, ¿ cómo has intentando solucionarlo ?

Comment: He intentado hacerlo con un split(':') y guardarlo en una lista pero no me funciona correctamente. @marmurar

Comment: Añade tu código para que podamos ayudarte !

Comment: Estoy en ello, pero no consigo avanzar ya que estoy escribiendo en una hoja de papel como funcionaria el programa, y no se me ocurre la manera aunque este bien documentado.

Comment: Introduce el código en el editor de texto que mas te guste y lo agregas :)

Comment: @marmurar añadí lo que llevo

Comment: Es necesario que hagas la extracción de la información del txt?, o sea por que no intentas leer el archivo

Comment: con pandas puedes hacer o con loadtxt de numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el ejercicio busca que utilices el método .split() y .replace() que son métodos del tipo de dato str, aquí te dejo una opción que aclaro solamente busca emplear ambos métodos para completar tu código:

```
def cambiar_texto_en_posicion(arg,ruta_archivo):
    # remueves los str en tu archivo spliteando el contenido de tu file que es un string:
    archivo = open(ruta_archivo, "r")
    datos   = archivo.read()
    datos   = datos.split(':')
    print('datos: ', datos)
    
    # Reemplazas los valores de la lista en el str que tomas como argumento:
    frase   = arg
    frase   = frase.replace('1', datos[0])
    frase   = frase.replace('2', datos[1])
    frase   = frase.replace('0', datos[2])
    print(frase)
    
    archivo.close()

cambiar_texto_en_posicion("1 juega con 2 y 0","<tu_path>")
```

Nota que:

1. No es la mejor versión de ese código dado que supones que siempre reemplazaras 0  1 y 2 por dentro del método.
2. No funciona si no pasas como argumento en tu string los valores 0 1 y 2
3. Esta sobre comentado A PROPÓSITO, no te aconsejo comentar cada línea y el solo con el propósito de entender y completar tu ejercicio.

Answer (score 2):

```
def cambiar_texto_en_posicion(arg, ruta_archivo):
    # remueves los str en tu archivo spliteando el contenido de tu file que es un string:
    archivo = open(ruta_archivo, "r")
    datos = [line.rstrip('\n').split(':') for line in archivo]

    print('datos: ', datos)

    # Reemplazas los valores de la lista en el str que tomas como argumento:

    frase = arg
    frase = frase.replace('1', datos[0][1])
    frase = frase.replace('2', datos[1][0])
    frase = frase.replace('0', datos[0][0])
    print(frase)

    archivo.close()


cambiar_texto_en_posicion("1 me dijo que 0 vendría con 2", "filename.txt")
```

**He automatizado la primera sección para la segunda como podría hacerla, he pensado con un bucle pero si hubiera otro método más eficiente me gustaría saberlo**

**Nuevamente Gracias con antelación**

Comment: @marmurar, gracias por el empujón.